# Electric Field of Patch Antenna

Tags: antenna, electromagnetic, pcb-antenna, patch-antenna

I am working on developing Patch antenna for 5G Applications. As the first step, I am trying to understand the working and properties of Microstrip patch antenna.

All the resources I have read state that electric field is zero at the center of patch, maximum at one side and minimum at another. However, I haven't come across any solid proof or even explanation for the same.

If anyone could enlighten me on this, it would be really helpful !

Comment: You are discussing your general issue here. Which is related to research. You can search these thigs on google

Comment: You can simulate it with programs like CST studio or HFSS to observe what you want to know. It seperates Electric and Magnetic field and draw it in 3D. There are plenty tutorial videos on youtube.

Comment: @mastermind I understand that this is a general issue however I have done quite some research on this without any results. Hence, I came to this platform. If you can suggest some resources, it would be really helpful.

Comment: @CanSevgi I am trying to understand the reason behind this behavior of electric field. HFSS will only simulate it without giving substantial reason behind this phenomenon.